# VSCode Remote SSH commands not found on Chromebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, chromebook, vscode-remote

I have successfully installed Visual Studio Code on my ASUS C101P thanks to the ARM64 build by https://code.headmelted.com/
Unfortunatly when I try to run any command from any of the Remote Development extensions the command errors with a "command not found" error, e.g.:

> command 'opensshremotes.addNewSshHost' not found

Is this because the plugins don't support ARM64, so some linking is failing somewhere, or has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing the same issue. I have installed vscode for arm64 by https://code.headmelted.com/ on nvidia jetson nano. What I have read from [here](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/240) is microsoft remote extensions are closed source. The license states that you can only use it with official microsoft products. And the remote server actively prevents OSS versions from connecting.

Comment: microsoft being microsoft